# What does this postgresql command prompt (> mean?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a postgresql db file, I just updated a table and the command prompt changed from  `=>` to `(>`.

What does this mean?

```
teamwork=> CREATE TABLE posts ( postId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, createdOn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, userID SERIAL REFERENCES users (userId), title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, article VARCHAR, imageUrl VARCHAR;
teamwork(>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have an unbalanced parentheses.

```
 teamwork=> CREATE TABLE posts ( postId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, createdOn
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, userID SERIAL REFERENCES users (userId), title
 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, article VARCHAR, imageUrl VARCHAR; 
 teamwork(>
```

Notice the ( after `posts` is not closed before the ; at the end.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you Will. I have corrected the statement, but still showing the <). How do I remove it?

Comment: You have to break out of the command it is trying to finish reading.  You can enter `\r<return>` to clear the buffer, or hit ctrl-C to do the roughly the same thing.  Or you can finish typing the command by entering `);<return>`, after which you will get a syntax error but will start over at a clean prompt.